# Brewing when sick person is on premises

Tags: brewing

I brew at home, where quite a few other persons live too. One of them has catched a common cold. Is there risk of sick person contaminating batch and if such a risk exists could common cold or similar mild infection causing viruses and/ or bacteria survive in wort post boil and if they do, how long could they survive?

Usually I have postponed brewing or any other brew related activities at such an event, but as spring is coming quite early this year, I'm running out of brewing season.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. There are no know pathogens that can survive in beer, wine or any booze. You are safe.

Comment: While I agree completely with the spirit of this post, I feel compelled to point out that certain pathogens absolutely *can* survive in beer, albeit for limited periods of time (dependent on alcohol content, pH, bitterness, temperature of storage, inoculation rate of pathogen &c). An interesting study of this can be found here: https://meridian.allenpress.com/jfp/article-lookup/doi/10.4315/0362-028X.JFP-10-546 I think it would be safer to say that no known pathogen can *grow/multiply/survive indefinitely* in *almost any beer* (the notable exception being non-alcoholic beer).

Comment: Of course, I'll stress that this really is no concern whatsoever as far as the poster's stated question is concerned.